# Check if default output goes to a terminal in R

Tags: r, terminal, tty

How can I check if output goes to a terminal in R?

I found `file.info()` but as far as a file type is concerned, it seems to only support

```
isdir: logical: Is the file a directory?
```

and it doesn't seem to support arguments like `stdout()` or `stderr()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `isatty()` on a R `connection`, just like you would use it in `libc` on a file descriptor:

```
R> isatty(stdout())
[1] TRUE
```